# Outlook on Send via Office 365

Tags: outlook-web-addins

I am a bit confused on the Outlook on Send feature. Is it supported with hosted Office365 with Windows Desktop client. 
If not what other way is there to have the system make a call to my back end to have some validation done ? Currently my users have to click in my plugin to validate and then send the send bttn of the mail client. Ideally i would like to intercept the send request, make my call to my backend and once validated return the transformed email and send it.
Can i go and trigger a send request from my plugin or is the only way to go and use the graph interface to send the message ? I rather not do that if possible as i will have to handle attachments and images as well.

Answer (score 0):

The "on send" feature is only currently available for Outlook Online, not for Outlook for Windows or Mac.  However, it will do exactly what you need to do in terms of validating the email and allowing or blocking the send. The only other integration option is a COM add-in, which will allow you to intercept either the active email's send event or all send events in the application.

Comment: Is there a time table for when it will be avail for outlook for windows ?

Comment: That's for Microsoft to answer. However, due to security concerns I doubt they will ever expose this feature for the desktop. You can vote for it here: https://officespdev.uservoice.com/.